# vim: how to run a command on a specific window on startup

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm on gvim 7.3 on windows.

I am using the [Tail Bundle](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1714) plugin, but in order to overcome a limitation on windows, I need to run some command on startup...BUT ONLY on the window/buffer that the plugin opens, not in the others.

This plugin opens a preview window, and if I ls, I dont see a buffer with the file I opened with this plugin...so my intent to use autocmd to limit somehow the action to only that buffer seems not doable.

Is there any way to run a command only on a specific preview window opened by this pluging? I guess so but I am quite a newbie in vim yet...

---

EDIT: ok, thanks to Kev, this part is solved, I leave open for the main question...

Aslo, as an addendum, I am running some commands on startup with

```
 -c "tabn"
```

this works well, but when I try to run somethign like `-c "<C-W> H"` those dont work, how can I do this?

Comment: "This plugin opens a preview window, and if I ls, I dont see a buffer with the file I opened with this plugin...so my intent to use autocmd to limit somehow the action to only that buffer seems not doable." You lost me. You want to limit an autocmd to a buffer that doesn't exist?

Comment: as I said, I just started using Vim, so I might be using incorrect tems. I want to send a command on startup that only applies to that preview window opened by the plugin

Comment: if that preview window has a reliable name then you can match that in the autocmd. For instance, `au WinEnter __Plugin_Window_Name__ echo "do something here"`

Comment: Not sure how to find out the 'window name', I am trying to use the label shown in the tab or the value in tooltip, but to no avail. Echo should echo to the command line no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin uses a preview-window (see `:h preview-window`) to display the file it's tracking. Unfortunately, I don't think there is an event you can trigger when a preview-window is opened, so the only way to do this is to edit the plugin itself and add your command when it opens the window.

Answer (score 1):

`-c` option only accept a `ex` command (AKA colon-command).
You need to re-write it as `-c 'exe "norm \<C-w>H"'`
Another way is `-c 'wincmd H'`